# como puedo filtrar los datos que muestro via solicitud ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Quiero filtrar los datos que me retorna la petición AJAX para obtener solo los que empiezen con las letras *vmi*.

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
  'dom': 'Bfrtip',
  'buttons': [{
      extend: 'excelHtml5',
      className: 'btn btn-primary',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: ':visible'
      }
    },
    {
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      className: 'btn btn-primary',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: ':visible'
      }
    },
    {
      extend: 'colvis',
      className: 'btn btn-primary',
      text: 'Columnas Visibles'
    }
    //'colvis'
  ],
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": -1,
    "visible": false
  }],
  "autoWidth": true,
  "ajax": {
    "url": "http://rev.zom.com.mx/extranete/WSs/Servicfios.svc/buscaRefer",

    "type": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "data": function(d) {
      return data2;
    },
    "dataSrc": function(json) {
      console.log(json.data.length);
      for (var i = 0, ien = json.data.length; i < ien; i++) {



      }
      return json.data;

    }

  },

  "error": function(jqXmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //alert("Datos Incorrectos"); //#coment
  }

});
```

La estructura del JSON que se retorna es la siguiente:

```
{
   "data":[
      [
         "-",
         "ALME18-00007",
         "5",
         "16/03/2018",
         "3843",
         "810",
         "8000045",
         "03/01/2018",
         "03/01/2018",
         "04/01/2018"
      ],
      [
         "-",
         "LCE18-00044",
         "6",
         "10/01/2018",
         "3843",
         "510",
         "8000077",
         "20/01/2018",
         "20/01/2018",
         "18/01/2018"
      ],
      [
         "-",
         "MAN18-00002",
         "4",
         "15/03/2018",
         "3235",
         "160",
         "8000040",
         "07/01/2018",
         "12/01/2018",
         "18/01/2018"
      ],
      [
         "-",
         "VMI18-00001",
         "1",
         "15/03/2018",
         "3843",
         "430",
         "8000068",
         "15/01/2018",
         "16/01/2018",
         "18/01/2018"
      ],
      [
         "-",
         "VMI18-00002",
         "3",
         "16/03/2018",
         "3843",
         "430",
         "8000070",
         "15/01/2018",
         "16/01/2018",
         "18/01/2018"
      ]
   ]
}
```

Comment: Cual es la estructura de tu json retornado?

Comment: ASi esta 

{"data":[["-","ALME18-00007","5","16/03/2018","3843","810","8000045","03/01/2018","03/01/2018","04/01/2018"],["-","LCE18-00044","6","10/01/2018","3843","510","8000077","20/01/2018","20/01/2018","18/01/2018"],["-","MAN18-00002","4","15/03/2018","3235","160","8000040","07/01/2018","12/01/2018","18/01/2018"],["-","VMI18-00001","1","15/03/2018","3843","430","8000068","15/01/2018","16/01/2018","18/01/2018"],["-","VMI18-00002","3","16/03/2018","3843","430","8000070","15/01/2018","16/01/2018","18/01/2018"]]}

Comment: Por favor, en tus próximas preguntas sé un poco más claro y explícito :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa el método [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para filtrar por el predicado deseado:

```
...
"dataSrc": json => json.data.filter(arr => arr[1].startsWith('VMI')),
...
```

Comment: funciona pero no hace el filtro y la salida sigue pasando todos los datos 
¿como guardo el resultado del filtro en json.data?

Comment: @emanuelle He actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: Eres un mastrazo !!  te agradesco mucho brother

Comment: De nada. Si te sirvió la respuesta puedes indicarlo marcándola como correcta (check debajo de la votación).